# "Array dimensions exceeded supported range" when creating a dataframe

Tags: c#, .net, apache-spark

I'm getting this exception when trying to create a DataFrame with only 50 millions rows. Any ideas how to avoid this problem?

```
[Exception] [JvmBridge] Array dimensions exceeded supported range.
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.set_Capacity(Int32 value)
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.EnsureCapacity(Int32 value)
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at Microsoft.Spark.Interop.Ipc.SerDe.Write(Stream s, String value)
   at Microsoft.Spark.Interop.Ipc.PayloadHelper.ConvertArgsToBytes(MemoryStream destination, Object[] args, Boolean addTypeIdPrefix)
   at Microsoft.Spark.Interop.Ipc.PayloadHelper.ConvertArgsToBytes(MemoryStream destination, Object[] args, Boolean addTypeIdPrefix)
   at Microsoft.Spark.Interop.Ipc.PayloadHelper.BuildPayload(MemoryStream destination, Boolean isStaticMethod, Int32 processId, Int32 threadId, Object classNameOrJvmObjectReference, String methodName, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.Spark.Interop.Ipc.JvmBridge.CallJavaMethod(Boolean isStatic, Object classNameOrJvmObjectReference, String methodName, Object[] args)
System.Threading.SemaphoreFullException: Adding the specified count to the semaphore would cause it to exceed its maximum count.
   at System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim.Release(Int32 releaseCount)
   at Microsoft.Spark.Interop.Ipc.JvmBridge.CallJavaMethod(Boolean isStatic, Object classNameOrJvmObjectReference, String methodName, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.Spark.Interop.Ipc.JvmBridge.CallJavaMethod(Boolean isStatic, Object classNameOrJvmObjectReference, String methodName, Object arg0, Object arg1)
   at Microsoft.Spark.Interop.Ipc.JvmBridge.CallNonStaticJavaMethod(JvmObjectReference jvmObject, String methodName, Object arg0, Object arg1)
   at Microsoft.Spark.Interop.Ipc.JvmObjectReference.Invoke(String methodName, Object arg0, Object arg1)
   at Microsoft.Spark.Sql.SparkSession.CreateDataFrame(IEnumerable`1 data, StructType schema)
   at Submission#29.<<Initialize>>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.ScriptExecutionState.RunSubmissionsAsync[TResult](ImmutableArray`1 precedingExecutors, Func`2 currentExecutor, StrongBox`1 exceptionHolderOpt, Func`2 catchExceptionOpt, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Comment: You seem to hit the 2GB barrier for a memory block in .Net. Looking at the source of the JvmBridge i don't see a way getting rid of the MemoryStream that tries to hold the complete data in Memory. You may try  to allow larger memory objects by setting gcAllowVeryLargeObjects in your config file. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcallowverylargeobjects-element

Answer (score 1):

Close all Visual Studio instances. Update your visual studio from Visual Studio Installer and re-open your project once update is done. Worked for me.